# how to solve "Undefined variable:id"

Tags: codeigniter

```
function empAll()
{     
  $this->db->where('id',$id);
  $q = $this->db->get('employee');        
  if($q->num_rows()>0)
   {    
     foreach($q->result() as $rows)
      {      
        $data[]=$rows;
      }
  return $data;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally we pass id in the Url:

Base_url()/index.php/empAll/25. Now codeigniter automatecaly pass the $id = 25 in the method. In case id not received it will assign the id by 0 and then you will not get this error.

```
function empAll()
        {     
          $q = $this->db->where('id',$this->input->post('id'))    
                        ->get('employee');        
          if($q->num_rows()>0)
           {    
             foreach($q->result() as $rows)
              {      
                $data[]=$rows;
              }
            }
          return $data;
         }
```